# UIImagepicker controller app crashes when start video in ios11, but it works on ios 10

Tags: objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

This code is working fine on ios 10 but it crashes on ios 11 when I present picker

```
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
 {
     UIImagePickerController *pickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
     pickerController.delegate = self;
     pickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
     pickerController.showsCameraControls = YES;
     pickerController.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie]; // kUTTypeMovie is actually an NSString.
     pickerController.videoMaximumDuration = 30.0f; // limits video length to 30 seconds.
     [self presentViewController:pickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
 }

// Picker Delegate

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)info
{
     self.videoURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
     [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion: nil];
     NSString *str = [self.videoURL absoluteString];
}
```

Comment: Put some crash logs, add exception breakpoints and let us know the details.

Comment: Xcode doesn't show the error even on adding exception breakpoint.
When I present the picker controller it crashes.

Comment: see the crashlogs from the device if possible by pressing `Shift + Cmd + 2`

Comment: I have found the issue. It is due to microphone permission.
Now its working fine.

Comment: @Aman Can i get a minimal debug repo? It will be easier for us.